# flex : add/edit//delete from database 

Tags: java, apache-flex

i have datagrid in my flex application,i am binding datagrid using Arraycollection(getting data from java class using remoteobject method call).
now i am performing add/edit/delete in datagrid i want this change should be reflect in database.
how can i do this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fully implement the [CRUD functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) in your java class. Then you can invoke these functions via RemoteObject calls.

Comment: @splash..at the time of inserting new data,how can i cast flex Value Object to java object?

Comment: Please read about [Using RemoteObject components](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/data_access_4.html#202412). Flex supports serializing between ActionSript and Java Objects, so you have to annotate your "Flex Value Object" with `[RemoteClass]` to reference a matching Java Object.